# How to interpret p values obtained with $\chi^2$-test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I have the following observed and expected values and I am trying to determine the goodness of fit with $\chi^2$ test. On calculating the p I obtain the value 0.9999742, but how is it possible that even with big differences in observed and expected values, I am getting p values close to 1. The data used is given below:

```
Observed    Expected
97.83   90.90
95.06   90.50
92.54   89.50
97.69   92.90
93.76   91.20
93.36   91.70
93.37   91.40
99.29   94.20
101.57  96.80
97.88   93.30
98.71   94.40
75.31   70.20
72.52   71.20
67.75   68.40
77.97   74.20
78.42   74.60
72.62   72.00
82.29   77.80
90.26   83.00
76.32   73.50
78.78   76.70
79.96   82.60
```

Even with such differences, can p be close to 1?

Comment: How did you compute your chi-square value?

Comment: There was a built in function CHITEST on LibreOffice spreadsheets. The documentation for the function mentions CHITEST returns the probability of a deviance from a random distribution of two test series based on the chi-squared test for independence.

Comment: Okay, now this is very important: How did you get the observed and expected?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember the formula for chi-sq is

> (**Observed** - **Expected**)^2 / **Expected**

With your data, I found a chi-sq of `4.12`, with a degree of freedom of 22-1 = 21, it is still not significant.

To answer your question, chi-sq can be any positive number, but you have to refer to the table to determine the fit.

Comment: That chi-square formula applies to count data. Clearly this is not count data.

Comment: @Glen_b I wasn't aware of that .., but I suppose grouping the observed values into categories and perform a chi-square test is plausible?  But then a model is needed to calculate the expected counts.

Comment: Yes, you are right $\chi^2$ = 4.12. It is the p value that is close to 1.